# Nativescript app showing scanty/few ui elements on ios emulator

Tags: typescript, nativescript, mobile-development

After running my app on android emulator it renders correctly but on ios emulator I have a scanty ui screen. Please what could I be doing wrong ?

I started the app using `ns run ios`. But then i was expecting to see my full ui components loaded but on my screen i have just few components showing up, few titles a pic and nothing else

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure what part of my code I am to share. Can you make a request?